# Create a new column, grouping info from other columns in Teradata

Tags: mysql, sql, teradata

Having this:

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION;

CREATE TABLE MY_TABLE(Salary integer, Name text, Country text);

INSERT INTO MY_TABLE VALUES(10,'Tom', 'Albania');
INSERT INTO MY_TABLE VALUES(20,'Lucy', 'Bulgaria');
INSERT INTO MY_TABLE VALUES(30,'Frank', 'Bulgaria');
INSERT INTO MY_TABLE VALUES(30,'Jane', 'Canada' );
INSERT INTO MY_TABLE VALUES(50,'Robert', 'Canada');
INSERT INTO MY_TABLE VALUES(50,'Robert2', 'Canada');
INSERT INTO MY_TABLE VALUES(100,'Robert2', 'Canada');
INSERT INTO MY_TABLE VALUES(50,'Robert3', 'Canada');
INSERT INTO MY_TABLE VALUES(60,'Robert6', 'Denmark');

COMMIT;

SELECT Salary, Name, Country,Salary || Country AS 'New' FROM MY_TABLE
WHERE Salary < 100
```

Producing this:

| Salary | Name | Country | New |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 10 | Tom | Albania | 10Albania |
| 20 | Lucy | Bulgaria | 20Bulgaria |
| 30 | Frank | Bulgaria | 30Bulgaria |
| 30 | Jane | Canada | 30Canada |
| 50 | Robert | Canada | 50Canada |
| 50 | Robert2 | Canada | 50Canada |
| 50 | Robert3 | Canada | 50Canada |
| 60 | Robert6 | Denmark | 60Denmark |

**The question:**
Instead of the value in `New`, I want to have a subsequent number, that is the same for all equal strings. E.g., something like this:

| Salary | Name | Country | New |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 10 | Tom | Albania | 1 |
| 20 | Lucy | Bulgaria | 2 |
| 30 | Frank | Bulgaria | 3 |
| 30 | Jane | Canada | 4 |
| 50 | Robert | Canada | 5 |
| 50 | Robert2 | Canada | 5 |
| 50 | Robert3 | Canada | 5 |
| 60 | Robert6 | Denmark | 6 |

The number 5 is the same, because **50Canada** is repeated 3 times in the table above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to use `dense_rank` window function.

```
SELECT *,dense_rank() OVER(ORDER BY Salary,Country) new
FROM MY_TABLE
WHERE Salary < 100
```